# strange values stored and retrieved in database

Tags: android-sqlite

My database code looks like this:
Activity:

```
public class GenerateQrCodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    
    boolean flag = false;
    String data_bus_number=null;
    String data_bus_number2=null;
    int ID_bus_number = -1;
    int status = -1;

    void updateLastDataAsInvalid(int id,String number)
    {
        myDb.updateData(id,number,"route","city",0);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ......
        ......
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this,edit);
        //myDb.deleteDatabase();
       
        Cursor cursor = myDb.getLastData();
        edit2.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
        flag = false;
        if(cursor!=null)
        {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    flag = true;

                    data_bus_number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NUMBER"));
                    ID_bus_number = (cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                    status = (cursor.getColumnIndex("STATUS"));
                    data_bus_number2+=String.valueOf(ID_bus_number)+"+"+data_bus_number+"+"+String.valueOf(status)+"+";
                    edit.setText(data_bus_number2);
                   } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
```

Database helper class :

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BusDetails.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "bus_details_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "NUMBER";
    public static final String COL_3 = "ROUTE";
    public static final String COL_4 = "CITY";
    public static final String COL_5 = "STATUS";
    Context cntxt;
    EditText edit;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context, EditText edit1) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        cntxt = context;
        edit = edit1;

    }

    public void deleteDatabase() {
        // Are you sure? (y/n)
        final SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        final File dbFile = new File(db.getPath());
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(cntxt, "db deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        edit.setText("db deleted");
        if (dbFile.exists()) {
            SQLiteDatabase.deleteDatabase(dbFile);

        }
        //mOpenHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NUMBER TEXT,ROUTE TEXT,CITY TEXT,STATUS INTEGER)");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String number,String route,String city,int status) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,number);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,route);
        contentValues.put(COL_4,city);
        contentValues.put(COL_5,status);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
        return res;
    }

    public Cursor getLastData() {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String query = "select * from "+ TABLE_NAME +" WHERE STATUS = 1";

        Cursor cursor = null ;

        try{
            cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
        }catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Log.d("error",ex.toString());
        }
        return cursor ;
    }

    public Cursor getEnteredData(String data) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String query = "select * from "+ TABLE_NAME +" WHERE NUMBER = "+data;

        Cursor cursor = null ;

        try{
            cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
        }catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Log.d("error",ex.toString());
        }
        return cursor ;
    }

    public boolean updateData(int id,String number,String route,String city,int status) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1,id);
        contentValues.put(COL_2,number);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,route);
        contentValues.put(COL_4,city);
        contentValues.put(COL_5,status);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?",new String[] {String.valueOf(id) });
        return true;
    }

   
}
```

When Activity starts, it retrieves data rows with
`status = 1`
with the help of
`myDb.getLastData()`
which stores results in
`Cursor cursor`
Then iterate through the cursor with:

```
if(cursor!=null)
            {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        flag = true;
    
                        data_bus_number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NUMBER"));
                        ID_bus_number = (cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                        status = (cursor.getColumnIndex("STATUS"));
                       data_bus_number2+ = String.valueOf  (ID_bus_number) + "+"+data_bus_number+ "+" +String.valueOf(status)+"+";
                    edit.setText(data_bus_number2);
                       } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
```

AND:

```
contents of data_bus_number2= null+0+data_bus_number(text)+4+0+data_bus_number+4+
```

which means
there are 2 rows
1st row->
previous data is null
id is 0  which is wrong should be 1 or any other number; wrong data is entered through myDb.insertData()
data_bus_number(text)is something that is correct
status is 4 which is wrong value status should be either 1 or 0;wrong data can only be entered through `updateLastDataAsInvalid(ID_bus_number,data_bus_number)` which described later;but strangely it retrieves records where status should be 1 by use of myDb.getLastData()

2nd row->
id is 0  which is wrong should be 2 or any other number
data_bus_number(text) is something that is correct
status is 4which is wrong value status should be either 1 or 0

when a new data comes, this statement hols true->

```
if((data_bus_number==null) || (data.compareTo(data_bus_number)!=0))
```

So, it should execute->

```
if((data_bus_number==null) || (data.compareTo(data_bus_number)!=0))
                    {
                        myDb.insertData(data, "route", "city",1);
                        if(data_bus_number!=null)
                            updateLastDataAsInvalid(ID_bus_number,data_bus_number);
                        edit2.setText(data+"data_bus_number-different text"+String.valueOf(ID_bus_number));
                    }
```

myDb.insertData takes care of inserting data, why is id not updated?

updateLastDataAsInvalid-> body is->

```
void updateLastDataAsInvalid(int id,String number)
    {
        myDb.updateData(id,number,"route","city",0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

done ->
changing->

```
ID_bus_number = (cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                    status = (cursor.getColumnIndex("STATUS"));
```

to:

```
ID_bus_number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                    status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("STATUS"));
```